# copy required data from one file to another file in python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python and am stuck at this I have a file `a.txt` which contains 10-15 lines of html code and text. I want to copy data which matches my regular expression from one `a.txt` to `b.txt`. Suppose i have a line `Hello "World" How "are" you` and I want to copy data which is between double quotes i.e. `World` and `are` to be copied to new file.

This is what i have done.

```
if x in line:
  p = re.compile("\"*\"")
  q = p.findall(line)
  print q
```

But this is just displaying only " "(double quotes) as output. I think there is a mistake in my regular expression.
any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex (which translates to `"*"` without all the string escaping) matches zero or more quotes, followed by a quote.

You want

```
p = re.compile(r'"([^"]*)"')
```

**Explanation:**

```
"     # Match a quote
(     # Match and capture the following:
[^"]* # 0 or more characters except quotes
)     # End of capturing group
"     # Match a quote
```

This assumes that you never have to deal with escaped quotes, e. g.

```
He said: "The board is 2\" by 4\" in size"
```

Answer (score 1):

Capture the group you're interested in (ie, between quotes), extract the matches from each line, then write them one per line to the new file, eg:

```
import re

with open('input') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        matches = re.findall('"(.*?)"', line)
        fout.writelines(match + '\n' for match in matches)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying so quick